# Select multiple checkboxes without toggling

Tags: reactjs, gatsby, next.js

I am new to react. I am trying to create a component that hides a div when a checkbox is clicked. The problem I am having is, if I introduce more than one checkbox the divs visibility is toggled. Is there an alternative way to allow the selection of all checkboxes?

The functionality should be: click a checkbox or multiple > div remains hidden until all checkboxes are cleared or unchecked.

JSX:

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';

function reactComponent() {
  const [isChecked, setIsChecked] = useState(false);
  const toggle = () => setIsChecked(!isChecked);

  return (
    <div>
      <div>
        <input type="checkbox" id="option" name="option" onClick={toggle} />
        <label for="scales">option</label>
      </div>

      <div>
        <input type="checkbox" id="option" name="option" onClick={toggle} />
        <label for="scales">option</label>
      </div>

      <div className={isChecked ? "hide" : "block "}>
        <h3 className="red bold">Content</h3>
        <p>lorem Ipsum</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  )
}
export default reactComponent
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To achieve what you've described you could use controlled inputs for checkboxes and have a separate piece of state for every checkbox. Here is [Codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/zealous-bas-n931p) demo of an example below (you can change `some` to `every` in `shouldShow` flag if you need to show the div if and only if all the checkboxes are checked).

```js
function App() {
  const [isChecked, setIsChecked] = useState({ option1: false, option2: false })
  const toggle = ({ target: { name } }) =>
    setIsChecked({ ...isChecked, [name]: !isChecked[name] })

  // Are there any checked ones?
  const shouldShow = Object.values(isChecked).some(val => val)

  return (
    <>
      <div>
        <input
          type="checkbox"
          id="option1"
          name="option1"
          checked={isChecked.option1}
          value={isChecked.option1}
          onClick={toggle}
        />
        <label for="option1">option1</label>
      </div>

      <div>
        <input
          type="checkbox"
          id="option2"
          name="option2"
          checked={isChecked.option2}
          value={isChecked.option2}
          onClick={toggle}
        />
        <label for="option2">option2</label>
      </div>

      <div className={shouldShow ? "hide" : "block "}>
        <h3 className="red bold">Content</h3>
        <p>lorem Ipsum</p>
      </div>
    </>
  )
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you render your checkboxes from an array, you can always check if the length of that array is the same as the length of the checked array kept in state.

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import "./styles.css";

function App() {
  const myOptions = ["option1", "option2", "option3", "option4"];
  const [myChecked, setMyChecked] = useState([]);

  const toggle = e => {
    e.persist();
    if (e.target.checked) {
      setMyChecked(oldArray => [...oldArray, e.target.name]);
    } else {
      setMyChecked(oldArray => oldArray.filter(item => item !== e.target.name));
    }
  };

  const showDiv = () => {
    return myChecked.length === myOptions.length;
  };

  return (
    <div>
      {myOptions.map(option => (
        <div>
          <label>
            <input type="checkbox" name={option} onChange={toggle} />
            {option}
          </label>
        </div>
      ))}

      <div className={showDiv() ? "block" : "hide "}>
        <h3>Content</h3>
        <p>lorem Ipsum</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<App />, rootElement);
```

[Codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/condescending-water-emyqw)